# Fetch an xml api in react hooks returns an undefined array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xml, react-hooks, fetch-api

I've been trying to fetch an xml api and display the data in the jsx but when I run the code below I get the error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): data.map is not a function

Would love to get some hints about what I'm doing wrong.

```
import './App.css';

const useFetch = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.text();
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let xml = parser.parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');

    let lastname = xml.getElementsByTagName('lastname');
    setData(lastname);
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  return { data, loading };
};

function App() {
  const { data, loading } = useFetch(
    'https://...'
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {loading ? (
        <p>loading...</p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {data.map((li) => {
            <li>{li.textContent}</li>;
          })}
        </div>
      )}

      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is `data` an array?

Comment: yes it is @Rashomon

Comment: The getElementsByTagName() method returns NodeList and map() is a method of  Array